# How to make "for(var i = 0;i<...)" by press TAB in Visual Studio code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio 2017 (C# development) when I write `for` and then press **tab** twice, it can generate something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

}
```

but in Visal Studio Code, Javascript development, when I write `for` and then press **tab** twice, it can't make that, how can I make that by pressing **tab** in Visual Studio Code

```
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    const element = array[index];

}
```

Comment: Check: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_default-keyboard-shortcuts -
* PS: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ *

Comment: Those that VTC "*Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User. "*, This question **clearly** involves tools primarily used for programming.

Comment: Sigh.... I voted to reopen.  The question is about how to create a snippet in vscode - clearly on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to create a snippet.  There are other answers about how to do that for javascript.

Your particular snippet would look like this:

```
"for int": {
    "prefix": "for",
    "body": [
      "for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)",
      "{",
      "$1",
      "}"
    ],
    "description": "my for loop"    
}
```

Now when you type "for" you will see a "for int" suggestion (or whatever you choose to put as the  identifier above [where I have put "for int" above] to distinguish it from the other for loop you don't want), select yours by arrowing down/up and tab to select.

VScode will learn your more frequently used snippets and soon you can just type "for" and hit "tab" and you will get your snippet.